# Do I understand these concepts correctly?

Tags: multithreading, web-services, grand-central-dispatch

In most of my interviews, I've been asked about web services and multithreading. I've done neither, so I decided to learn more about **Web Services** and **Multithreading using Grand Central Dispatch**.

1. For web services, the way that I understand it is that you need to fetch the data using a class such as `NSURLConnection`. basically setup a new `NSURL`, then a connection, then a request. You also need to make use of the API's methods such as `didConnect`, `didReceiveData`, and `didFailLoadWithError`. After you receive the data, which is generally in JSON or XML format and stored as an NSData object, you can store it and parse through it. There are multiple ways to parse through it, such as by using SBJSON or NSXMLParser. You can then do with it what you need.
2. For multithreading, Grand Central Dispatch is a c-style way of multithreading. Basically, you use it when you need to do heavy hauling away from the main thread to avoid the app freezing. You can dispatch synchronously or asynchronously. Asynchronously means that the method on the main thread will continue executing, synchronously means that it will not. You never need to use GCD alongside with `NSURLConnection`, because `NSURLConnection` already does its work in the background then calls upon delegates in the main thread. But, for saving and unzipping files, you should use GCD. When you call `dispatch_async`, you pass in a dispatch queue. You can use either a serial queue or a concurrent queue. A serial queue will execute tasks in the queue one at a time, in the order that they arrived. It is the default setting. With concurrently queues, tasks executed concurrently might be executed at the same time.

My first question is, do I have a proper understanding of these two concepts? I know that there is *a lot* to learn about GCD, but I just want to make sure that I have the basic ideas correct. Also, with GCD, why would someone ever want to dispatch synchronously, wouldn't that defeat the purpose of multithreading?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right place for such a 'question'

Comment: @MitchWheat I know, I wasn't sure if it was or not. Do you know what area of Stack this would be better in?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason to dispatch synchronously is to prevent the current code from continuing until the critical section finishes.

For example, if you wanted to get some value from the shared resource and use it right away, you would need to dispatch synchronously. If the current code does not need to wait for the critical section to complete, or if it can simply submit additional follow-up tasks to the same serial queue, submitting asynchronously is generally preferred.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation, that makes sense. Would you suggest I move this post to programmers.stackexchange?

Comment: this part `My first question is, do I have a proper understanding of these two things, up to midlevel interview standards?` remove that , and if you have question about interview or workplace try the site the programmer site

Comment: Sure thing, I just made the change. Thank you!

Comment: other than that I believe you understand the concept. do your best! good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can make synchronous request and dispatch it by using *dispatch_async* or *dispatch_sync* call. It will totally run in background.

```
-(void)requestSomething:(NSString *)url
{
    NSString *queue_id = @"queue_identifier";
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create([queue_id UTF8String], 0);
    dispatch_queue_t main = dispatch_get_main_queue();

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSURLRequest   *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        NSError        *serviceError = nil;
        NSURLResponse  *serviceResponse = nil;
        NSData *dataResponse = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&serviceResponse error:&serviceError];

        if(serviceError)
        {
            dispatch_sync(main, ^{

                // Do UI work like removing indicator or show user an alert with description of error using serviceError object.

                return;
            });
        }

        else
        {
            // Use dataResponse object and parse it as this part of code will not executed on main thread.

            dispatch_sync(main, ^{

                // Do UI work like updating table-view or labels using parsed data or removing indicator

            });
        }
    });

    // If your project is not developed under ARC mechanism, add following line
    dispatch_release(queue);
}
```

Comment: Remember : The “sync” part of the function name means that the code that comes after the _dispatch_sync_ call will not continue to run until the work inside the block is done. If we use "async" version of dispatch, the code after _dispatch_async_ will run concurrently i.e it will not wait for above code to execute.